# How can I upload an thumbnail image (blob) at the same time as an Entity into a datastore in google app engine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, blob, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I Just started using google app engine today, and I have fallen in love with endpoints.  I made one very easily that will store an object in the datastore that just has a few string values.  But I also want a small thumbnail image to go along with that datastore entity.  I understand how to upload blobs from android using an HttpServlet.  I was thinking of using the id of the datastore entity as the image's name in the blobstore, but I dont know how to connect the two events since I would upload the Entity to the datastore, and then the blob after that request.  Does anyone know how I can get an image in the blobstore somehow connected to the entity in the datastore so when I access the datastore i can also recall the blob associated with it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use [ImageService](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview#Transforming_Images_from_the_Blobstore) API in GAE to serve your images of different sizes and also you can apply various transformations on those images.

I am sharing you some code as well below so you will understand how I am serving the image urls using the stored blobkey.

```
String blobKeyString = blobKey.getKeyString();   // Returned value of blobkey when upload is done.
ImagesService services = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
ServingUrlOptions serve = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
String imageUrl = services.getServingUrl(serve);
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. Is there a solution for python as well?

Comment: Yes you will have similar APIs in python as well. I am not that much familiar with python.